# Can AMO physics be applicable for space travel?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, atomic-physics, rocket-science, space-mission

I know it sounds very stupid question.

I am working on the AMO physics (Quantum Optics). I recently saw articles about the Spacex, and I thought it is really amazing, and thinking about the possible AMO application to space project.

AMO is applicable for the accurate sensor/detector and future computation and communication. However, I cannot really see that it will be applicable for spaceship or Mars colonization project.

Anyone know that AMO can be applicable for the space project?

Comment: One of the things all future manned space missions will need are very reliable, very high speed optical data links to Earth with the lowest possible power consumption on the spacecraft. Did I mention radiation resistance? If you got something like that, the space community will love you. Not sure SpaceX is invested in these things (they should be), but NASA is, for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible application of AMO physics would be inertial guidance systems based on atomic interferometers--similar systems are currently being investigated for missile guidance and have shown much higher accuracy than other methods.  Inertial navigation systems don't rely on a network of GPS satellites, which obviously wouldn't be present on Mars (yet!)

Answer (score 1):

- As @EntropicallyDriven mentions, matter-wave interferometry can be used for inertial navigation.
- Better clocks (in terms of both performance and size / weight / power) would help with pulsar navigation.